# EJB using POJO as remote

Tags: java, ejb, pojo

I'm facing with a problem, that: I have 2 EJB applications deployed at 2 different servers (10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.221). In the first application, I have a POJO class (implements Serializable), and I use SerializationUtils from Apache to serialize its object (POJO pojo = new POJO(); then serialize it), and I send the object pojo to application number 2 as a message. I deserialize it (String className = SerializationUtils.deserialize(message).getClass().getSimpleName()), just want to get the class name, I expect that it will return "POJO", but I got ClassNotFoundException. Can anyone have a solution? Does @Remote useful in this case?
PS: I don't want add dependency between those apps. They should be independent.

Comment: You need to make the POJO class available to both applications, possibly by adding it to a shared library jar.

Comment: Many thanks, it solved the problem